# contextmenu event listner not working on right click inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to get the page html content when ever user does the right click. for that i have handled the contextmenu event . in event handler i used to get the html content. but if right click is done inside iframe its unable to call event handler.

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", handleContextMenu, false);
function handleContextMenu(event){
   var responseObj = {
       elementTarget : event.target.nodeName,
       href : event.target.getAttribute("href"),
       pageHtmlContent : event.currentTarget.querySelector("html").outerHTML
   }
   return responseObj;
}
```

Comment: so can i load the same script inside the iframe?

Comment: That depends on what else is there in the script file. If `handleContextMenu` is global, you can refer it from iframe though.Btw. Where exactly are you returning `responseObj`, what is the receiver of this object?